# How to customize login account for Login control in ASP.NET if we are authenticated by Micorosoft Federation?

Tags: asp.net, login-control, federation

currently I have a website with authentication using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule. It redirects me to login page (single sign-on outside my website) and upon login, I am redirected to default page.

Now, when I was using CreateUserWizard asp.net control, it seems that upon creation of user, the control tried to use my machine name to login to db server (i.e. '\$') instead of using SSO login which has just been done.

Does anybody know how to customize the control to use federation login to connect to db server? In addition, how to set so that the control will use certain specified sql account to login to db server?

Answer (score 0):

When you rely on federated identity, you typically won't "create users". Those would be handled by the identity provider. You might want to consider rethinking your app a little bit. For example: given that users will be provided for you (through the IdP), what does it make sense to do in your app? (e.g. associate users, manage authZ, etc). But likely not "create ones".

Comment: Uh, actually those users inside federated identity is normal users, which can access 'normal' features of websites. However, I have also my own aspnet membership database, which is actually stored the list of users assigned as admin (these users are part of users in federated identity). Now, I want my system to be able to create new admin IF the logged in user is one of the admin inside this aspnet membership database